# Opening/saving QGIS project .qgs in different version

Tags: qgis

I was working on the latest QGIS 2.10 Pisa version and saved my work in .qgs project, I tried to re-open the projects with QGIS 2.0.1 Dufour but I had a lot of visualization problem and everything was messed up!

Any hints about it?

Iis there a way to save or convert a qgs project in older versions?

Comment: I don't think it's possible to save as an older .qgs project file as the newer versions of QGIS would contain new functionalities and styles for visualization. Shouldn't be a problem loading old project files into a newer version of QGIS though.